# iOS app vanishing from Notification Center after update

Tags: ios, push-notification, titanium, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS app written in Titanium Studio using Push Notifications, Badges and Sounds through Urban Airship. After my last update people who upgraded are having problems with the Notification Center. At first my app still appears in the Notification Center, but the "Badges, Sounds, Banners" that normally appear under the app's name have vanished. If you go into the app's settings in the Notification center, the options to change these things simply are not there. Of course Push Notifications don't work at this point either.

Now, if you either restart the phone or reinstall the app, the programs entry in the notification center vanishes completely. I have found that after reinstalling the app and restarting the phone enough times the entry in the Notification Center will reappear and Pushes will work again. This is of course an absurd thing to ask all our users to do.

Even while all this is happening I still receive proper APID's from the phones, and the push messages claim to go though correctly. The phone just does not display them.

On the one fresh install I have tried everything worked great right off the bat.

I am completely stumped on where to go on this one. Any suggestions?

Edit 1:
Here is the relevant section of the code. I only changed one line from the previous version the only and only line of code to change from the previous version is noted.

```
var Urbanairship = require("com.0x82.urbanairship");
Urbanairship.options = {
  APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD: true, 
  DEVELOPMENT_APP_KEY: "xxx",
  DEVELOPMENT_APP_SECRET: "xxx",
  PRODUCTION_APP_KEY: "yyy",
  PRODUCTION_APP_SECRET: "yyy",
  LOGGING_ENABLED: true,
  LOG_LEVEL: 5
};

  Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
  types: [
    Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
    Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
    Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
  ],
  success: function(e){

    var token = e.deviceToken;
    Urbanairship.autoBadge = true;
    Urbanairship.pushEnabled = true; //Added this line, only line to change
    Urbanairship.registerDevice(token);
    userData.pushID = token; //save pushid
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
  },
  error: function(e){
    alert("The Push Servers appears to be down. Please restart the app and try again");
    if(DEBUG == true){Ti.API.debug("Apple Push Error: "+e.error)}
  },
  callback: function(e){
  pushReceived(e.data.type);
  }
})
```

Comment: Did you test this behaviour on multiple devices (not a single one that has a software problem)?

Comment: 5 devices. 2 iPads and 3 iPhones.

Comment: Could you provide a diff of your last update's code changes (related to push notifications)?

Comment: Sorry, but not really. Given enough time it seems to resolve it self, but the only way to hasten it seems to be just restarting and reinstalling until it works. Luckily this has not happened again with any of the following updates, I can only assume it is a bug in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If the notification settings have disappeared, it's unlikely to be a code problem. The code can only request notifications, it can't change the setting altogether.

It's possible that your update was built with an older provisioning profile, one that does not have push enabled. In the profile the "aps-environment" flag would not be found, and when the app attempts to register it will display this error in the xcode console:
https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60710-can-t-get-a-device-token-%22no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-%22-seen-in-console

If this is the issue, you can delete the existing provisioning profiles from your xcode installation for safety, and then modify and re-download the provisioning profile from the portal, and re-build and re-submit the app.

Comment: The odd thing is that given enough time the app reappears in the Notification Center. Then soon after that push messages start working again. Is this behavior we could expect from a provisioning profile issue?

Comment: I have never seen anything like that; if that is happening with an installed app without re-installing it, re-building it, or updating the provisioning profile, then it sounds like it might be a strange corner case or bug. I'd gather as much information as you can and file it with APple.